# How does the back button work on beautyoftheweb.com?

Tags: javascript, browser

I've been looking for some javascript hooks for the back button in the browser. But they only seem to support back/forward between hashed url's. That is, you can only navigate from `www.mysite.com#page1` and `www.mysite.com#page2`, if you click back, and the url becomes something without a hash, they all fail. Like this one: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/ Click one tab, then back, it won't work.

But on http://www.beautyoftheweb.com they've managed to get the backbutton to work between hashed and non-hashed url's. Any idea how they've done this?

Comment: Yuk, another "look at what our browser can do" site.

Comment: @jakenoble I don't really care about that, I'm only interested in that one specific feature. And it's a great looking site no matter which browser you use...

Comment: As always, these things are subject to perception. That site drives me nuts because it keeps me waiting for the information I want so it can do its pretty animations -- or at least, that's my perception. It's always possible it would keep me waiting *anyway*, and the animations are just there to pass the time. But I don't think so.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, well it's a showcase site. It's not about consuming information, just taking in how nicely things can be done. But as you say, these things are subjective, so I guess there's no reason to argue about the design...

Comment: No argument here. :-) Just saying: Pretty, but irritating to some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure? I'm seeing a hash:

```
http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/#/highlights/all-around-fast
                              ^-- here
```

But assuming there are some URLs that don't have them: What kind of failures are you seeing elsewhere? I have an intranet app where I'm using [Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) for history management, and you can happily go backward and forward between URLs whether or not they're application URLs using the hash, application URLs not using the hash, or completely unrelated URLs for other pages/apps. (You can also bookmark the hashed ones, and the app comes back to the right place when you use it.) That works in my app because on initial load, I look to see what hash (if any) is present and reload that state as necessary. (I don't rely on — or even use — RSH's data-storage aspect, just the hash manipulations.)

---

**Edit** Just tried the [live demo](http://nix.lv/history/demo.html) of the first [jQuery history plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history) I found in a quick search. It handled going back and forth between "hashed" and "unhashed" URLs just fine. I went to the "#2" link, then edited the URL in the address bar to remove the hash entirely and pressed Enter. That took me to the correct page. Then clicking Back I got the "#2" page correctly. In fact, if you [go here](http://nix.lv/history/demo.html#2) I'm linking directly to the "#2" link, and it loads its state accordingly. I think you've been seeing some naive use of history libraries where the coder hasn't handled the initial load correctly.

Comment: Yes, but when you click back, and the hash goes away, it still works as you'd expect the back button to. And that's what I've been having some problems getting. The history plugins only seem to work between hashtagged urls, but they won't work when you click back from a hashtagged url to a non-hashtag url.

Comment: @peirix: That's not my experience with RSH. Haven't tried any of the others. You *do* (at least with RSH) have to handle the initial load correctly for the hash to work right out of the box, perhaps you're just seeing people using the libs somewhat naively?

Comment: @peirix: In fact, I'm pretty sure that's what you're seeing; just updated my answer vis-a-vis a jQuery history plug.

Comment: But if you load the url without the hash to begin with, click "load 2", and then click back, it won't do anything. It will keep "2" loaded. And that's where I'm having problems. Going back to a non-hashed url, and reloading the initial content.

Comment: This still does not really address how thebeautyoftheweb site does it.  I just spent 15 minutes in the source trying to figure out what specifically they did, but there's quite a bit to sift through :-(

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, all the URLs are of the form `http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/#/<something>`, for example: http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/#/experience/cnn - hence, all are using hashes.

Comment: see my comment on T.J. Crowder's answer.